# Tkinter CPU intensive tasks with threading or multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have a tkinter application which starts a CPU intensive task on a button click and the progress of the task should be updated on a Progress Bar. Using [threading.Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread) class did not work because of Python's GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) (as per my knowledge). I tried using [multiprocessing.Process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) class but it didn't seem to work either. Can't I pass a callback to the new Process created, so that it will call that function to update the Progress Bar?

Please look at the example below:

```python
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from threading import Thread
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from tkinter.constants import HORIZONTAL
from multiprocessing import Process
import math

root = Tk()
root.title("Multiprocessing Demo")
root.geometry("500x400")

def cpu_intensive_task():
    math.factorial(210000)
    progress_bar['value'] = 50
    math.factorial(210000)
    progress_bar['value'] = 100
    root.update_idletasks()
    print("Done")
    

progress_bar = Progressbar(
    root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=500, mode="determinate"
)

progress_bar.pack(pady=20)

start_btn = Button(
    root,
    text="Start",
    command=Thread(target=cpu_intensive_task).start, # This freezes the GUI
    # command=Process(target=cpu_intensive_task).start, # This gives the mentioned error below

)
start_btn.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Error message when a Process instance is used:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 25 (Inappropriate ioctl for device) on X server ":0"
      after 1266 requests (1266 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python3: xcb_io.c:269: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
[1]    193933 abort (core dumped)  python3 multi.py
```

Using a shared queue and polling it doesn't seem to be a good solution either because we have to keep polling the queue in a loop and an event might be delayed by the time between two polls at maximum. Is there a way to achieve this without polling?

Comment: Create a function in which you start the thread or process. Then pass this function as command to button.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like, if you want to some information from your cpu:

```
import psutil
cpu_freq = psutil.cpu_freq()    # shows your current cpu freq // if you are on linux
                                # you can use // sensors_temperatures() to show the cpu temp
print(cpu_freq)
```